# how to save style in a wp-editor

Tags: wordpress

HI everyone I create a new text_area file to show in all my page.

this is the declaration

```
$sidebar_parallax = isset( $values['my_meta_box_text_sidebar_parallax'] ) ? $values['my_meta_box_text_sidebar_parallax'] : '';
```

I use like this

```
    <label for="my_meta_box_text">Sidebar Parallax text:</label>
    <?php wp_editor($sidebar_parallax_value, 'my_meta_box_text_sidebar_parallax', $settings = array('textarea_name'=>'my_meta_box_text_sidebar_parallax') ); ?>
```

and safe here

```
 if( isset( $_POST['my_meta_box_text_sidebar_parallax'] ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_meta_box_text_sidebar_parallax', wp_kses( $_POST['my_meta_box_text_sidebar_parallax'], $allowed ) );
```

my allowed value has

```
   $allowed = array( 
   'a' => array(
        'href' => array(),
        'title' => array()
    ),
    'br' => array(),
    'em' => array(),
    'strong' => array()
    );
```

the problem it is that don't save the style css, If I create a list with

- hello

. When I safe I only obtain  the word hello.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is inside your $allowed? You must pass the allowed html tags in this variable.
Ex:

```
array(
    'a' => array(
        'href' => array(),
        'title' => array()
    ),
    'br' => array(),
    'em' => array(),
    'strong' => array()
);
```

From https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses

Comment: Thank @enapupe I have the same in my $allowed but when I save the info in my database they don't have any formatted. Any idea

Comment: Did you passed li, ul?

Comment: thanks @enapupe yes, finally I add this element and word find. But is possible add any style css to this element. Thanks